# iPad Landscape View frame size

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

When I use ViewController.View.frame.size.width  and height in landscape mode, I am getting 768 and 1024 respectively where as I see 1024 and 768 from my Storyboard's "Size Inspector". Have anyone got any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an oddity (bug?) in iOS. But I'd wager that so many people have done kludgy workarounds (e.g., inspect the device orientation and if landscape, flip the `width` and `height`), that I'm not sure if Apple dare fix this, for fear of breaking tons of apps.

As an example of the strange behavior, if you have a navigation controller, for example, you'll find that the `frame.size` is correct as you go from portrait to landscape mode, but in the absence of a navigation controller, it isn't. If you're just looking for the width and height, you can frequently grab `bounds.size`, instead, which appears to get updated properly, regardless.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the `frame` for a view's dimension.  You have to use `bounds`.  More info is here: [My self.view has the wrong dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426016/my-self-view-has-the-wrong-dimensions/13426973#13426973)