# My self.view has the wrong dimensions

Tags: ios, uiview, autorotate, autosize

My view has the wrong dimensions. I am running a Landscape only but the view is reporting portrait dimensions "View Width = 768.000000 Height = 1024.000000" Any Ideas how to fix that? I have played around with the autorotate I have tried

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft|| interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

It looks fine on the view but have the dimensions are really messing with my app.

Comment: how are you getting the size of the view?

Comment: self.view.frame.size.width. Etc..

Comment: and when are you reading that value?

Comment: @yuf I have ran it at different parts. viewDidLoad and button press.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should never use `frame` to tell your own dimension.  `frame` is relative to the parent container view.  To find the dimension with respect to your view's own coordinate system, use `bounds`: `self.view.bounds`

For example, the parent view may see the child view having width = 768 and height = 1024, but with a rotate 90 degree transform.  This is how the parent view sees the child view, and this is what `self.view.frame` is about.  The child view having a width = 1024 and height = 768 is reflected by how a view sees itself in its own coordinate system, which is `self.view.bounds`

Comment: I tried using bounds but I still get the same results. I'm thinking that the view might not know that the iPad is in landscape. I don't know.

Comment: try printing out in `touchesBegan` and see if you see the same value?

Comment: That worked, Thats super weird do you know why its was doing that?

Comment: of the earliest time you can see it correctly are `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews`,  `viewDidAppear`. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118920/on-an-ios-single-view-app-when-is-the-earliest-time-that-self-view-bounds-is-se